Counting the points reached by diagonal movements in $\mathbb{Z}^2$
In the Cartesian plane, suppose a piece moves according to the following rule: starting from the point $(a, b)$, it can go to one of the points $(a + 1, b + 1)$, $(a + 1, b - 1)$, $(a - 1, b + 1)$, or $(a - 1, b - 1)$.
If the piece starts at the point $(0, 0)$, how many distinct positions can it occupy after its first $n$ moves?
I think that the answer is 1+2n(n+1), but I found solutions saying that the correct answer is (n+1)^2. Could anyone help me?

For $n=1$, the correct answer is $4$, but your formula gives $5$.

I note that all reachable points are either (odd, odd) or (even, even).  And they form a square grid, rotated 45 degrees from the coordinate grid...

@EricTowers. They do form a square grid but there’s no rotation involved. See my answer.

Although you already have an answer, it would help, generally, to say how you got $1+2n(n+1)$, so that your error can be identified, to help you avoid making that sort of mistake in the future.

Brian Tung,  see my "solution" below.

Gerry, for n=1 are 5 points (0,0), (1.1),(1,-1), (-1,1) and (-1,-1).

@Cgomes. After one step, you can’t be at the origin. You can only be at $(\pm1,\pm1)$, so there are only $4$ points. This is the conceptual mistake in your answer below.

Note that, after $n$ steps, $a\equiv b \equiv n\mod 2$. It is easy to see that there are no other restrictions on $(a,b)$ except for the trivial ones that $-n\le a\le n$ and $-n\le b\le n$. So we just have to count the integer points $(a,b)$ in the square $[-n,n]^2$ such that $a\equiv b \equiv n \mod 2$. The number of such points is $(n+1)^2$.

Update: Let me add some explanation to my answer. First, note that the horizontal and vertical motions are completely independent because at each step you move left/right and up/down independently. So we can solve for each direction separately.
Now, in the horizontal direction, after $n$ steps, you can reach $a=n-2k$ for some $0\le k\le n$ by moving $k$ units to the left and then $n-k$ units to the right. Moreover, these are the only points you can reach after $n$ steps. Therefore, there are $n+1$ possible values of $a$ after $n$ steps.
The same argument works for $b$ in the vertical direction. And as explained above, $a$ and $b$ can be chosen independently. Therefore, there are $(n+1)^2$ possible locations after $n$ steps.
The same argument works in $\mathbb Z^d$ for any $d$, so the answer in that case is $(n+1)^d$.

My "solution" is:Just to understand our reasoning later, let's start by showing the points that can be reached by taking $n=3$ steps.
Note that starting from the origin $(0,0)$ and taking $1$ step, we can reach $4$ new points, namely:
$$ (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1). $$
Taking another step, that is, for $n=2$, the number of new points that can be reached is $3\cdot 4 - 4=8$. Continuing in this way, when we take another step, that is, for $n=3$, $4\cdot 4 - 4 = 12$ new points can be reached (in green). Following this pattern, when moving from step $n-1$ to step $n$, $(n+1)\cdot 4 - 4 = 4n$ new points are added. See the table below:
Given the above, by defining $a_n$ as the total number of points that can be reached after taking $n$ steps, it follows that:
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + 4n, \ \forall \ n \geq 1, \ a_0=1 $$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{cases}
    a_0 = 1\\
    a_1 - a_0 = 4\cdot 1\\
    a_2 - a_1 = 4\cdot 2\\
    a_3 - a_2 = 4\cdot 3\\
    \vdots\\
    a_n - a_{n-1} = 4\cdot n
\end{cases}
$$
Adding these equations term by term, for all $n \geq 1$, it follows that:
$$ a_n = 1 + 4(1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n) = 1 + 4\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 1 + 2n(n+1). $$
where is my error?

The question doesn’t ask for “all the points visited so far while taking $n$ steps”, it asks for “all the points that you can be at after $n$ steps”. Do you see the difference between the two?

It's clear now. Thanks a lot Pranay.
